# How would you represent "religion" in an icon, neutrally?

Tags: icon, symbolism

I am involved in a web application where items in a list have a category. Each category of an item is shown through the use of an expressive icon. One of the categories is religion.

My coworker, a graphic designer, is at a loss on how he would represent religion in a logo "neutrally". Some of the items may be associated with Christianity, Islam, Buddhism, etc. so a religion-specific icon would not work and may be potentially offensive.

So, is there a way we can represent it in a different way?

Comment: Given that religion is hardly neutral, it might be best just write out the word instead of attempting an icon.

Comment: given that religion is hardly culturally universal, no. :)

Comment: I would say no. You can have 1 God, several Gods, and even no Gods in a religion. Starting with that, you'd already need at least 3 icons...

Comment: In most religions, folded hands is a gesture of prayer. How about using that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What about an icon depicting a set of praying hands?

Edit: It seems that Civilization 4 uses something similar: [Check out the seventh icon in the row of icons in the top-right corner of this screenshot, below "PM"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qD0fI.jpg).

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Most airports I've seen that have a **multi-faith room** use, if not just text, some human figure in what you could call a **prayer position**:

[image][image]

Answer (score 11):

Even Google Maps does not have a single symbol:

Patrick Hoffman is a user experience designer for Google - including Maps:

> "Google Maps visitors probably don't think twice about the little
>   pictures that dot its maps, but an icon's creation can be a fraught
>   process, he says. "Some of the best landmarks are places of worship
>   because they tend to have big steeples for example and are easily
>   recognisable. My challenge was to create one icon for a place of
>   worship, everyone said just use a cross, but of course you can't use a
>   cross because then you'll alienate synagogues and mosques."
>
> He opted for an icon that drew on common architectural features of
>   religious houses but that was criticised for being too close to
>   certain religions. Now, where it can, Google uses different symbols to
>   indicate different places of worship.

[Google Map symbols headache for creator](http://www.stuff.co.nz/technology/digital-living/4098069/Google-Map-symbols-headache-for-creator/)

Answer (score 5):

The icon used for religious places will differ from country to country.
Usually unique symbols that represents each religion is used.

Here is an example from a Sri Lankan map where it's 4 dominant religions are represented with 4 different icons.

[image: Religions in maps]

I'm not sure how universally accurate this is, but in most countries putting your hands together symbolizes prayers. So if it's difficult to have unique icons for each religion try something like this,

[image: Prayer icon]

Comment: Christians pray like that. Muslims pray by bowing to Mecca. Jewish people often pray holding their prayer book (although some pray the same way as above). If you use combined hands, you'll alienate Muslims and some Jews.

Answer (score 3):

At airports, in addition to the kneeling man and clasped hands, which others have already pointed out, I have seen a collective icon containing icons representing the "bigger" (by number of followers) religions.

[image: poly faith icon]

Answer (score 1):

in OS X 10.7 and up, there's an icon from the font Apple Emoji Colour, for referring to the religion: .

If you can't see this icon. Just see: http://fsymbols.com/thumbs/324.png (look at the right)

[image]

Comment: If you mean the last icon on the second row, you are mistaken! That's actually a high-five icon!

Comment: He is not mistaken because he associates this image with religion, and he is not the only one. As iOS user I've always associated this icon with prayer/religion until I've read your comment 30 seconds ago. And I've seen this icon in use by others only in context of "lets pray nothing bad happens" or "thank God something else happened". It is good that you know what it was originally meant for by the designers at Apple, but what matters most is what meaning people attach to it.

Comment: @Alph.Dev it would matter if it was text-to-speech translated as "Let's high-five nothing bad happens"

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your target audience.  Culturally universal, maybe not.

In the west, most people recognise a building with a cross on it as a religious establishment.  Even those that practice religions other than Christianity such Hinduism.

But in a Muslim country where Christian churches are less common and instead the local mosque is seen more commonly, may present itself as a more appropriate symbol for religion there.

But I would say something of the nature of a religious building would be recognised by the majority of people.