# How could I show hands that are race neutral?

Tags: design-principles, symbolism

I'm creating a graphic with a hand holding a phone, but I don't want to show any hand of race(black/white). I've seen once google use a a non-realistic hand and gray-scaling a hand looks even more awkward. Suggestions?

Comment: This question reminded me a little of this other one: [How would you represent “religion” in an icon, neutrally?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1132/how-would-you-represent-religion-in-an-icon-neutrally)

Comment: you want to show a hand, but not a realistic hand? If so, then that's your answer. Draw a hand without any particular color that would fall into the normal spectrum of skin colors.

Comment: @Yisela thanks for the article, that was interesting

Comment: So is it a photo-realistic hand you want? If so, put the hand in shadow with the light source behind it, and it could be any race.

Answer (score 8):

While DA01's answer makes it's point that there are a thousand-and-one ways to do this, I'd like to suggest a specific style that exhibits simplicity and professionalism without sacrificing anatomic accuracy.

[image]

[You can access the source of these icons here.](http://www.mobiletuxedo.com/touch-gesture-icons/) On the site, you'll see that there are versions holding and interacting with a phone in various ways; You will be able to use them either directly, or as a basis for your design.

Answer (score 7):

Have the hand wear a glove. The first example that comes to mind is a white mime's glove, but there should be other possible colours and designs.

Answer (score 5):

> How could I show hands that are race neutral?

By not using literal hand imagery. Any actual photo of a hand will inherently have a particular skin tone.

As such, turn to illustration:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]